# ADF validations and mandatory fields

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-adf, requiredfieldvalidator, required-field

I need to add a validation in the following way.

There's a drop-down list with two attributes(let them be A1 & A2) and an Input Text box. I need to let the text box become mandatory(Required) if and only if A1 is selected in the drop-down list.

I know the way to do this using validations. But I need to do this using the expression builder for mandatory(Required) property in the properties tab.

I'm using Oracle JDeveloper 12c

Hope there's a way to do this, please let me know if anybody knows the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to the Expression Builder for 'required' in your field. You'll get it right.

```
#{bindings.typeId1.inputValue eq 'A1'}
```